# Installing SSH Server on RHEL 8.4

Tags: ssh, redhat, dnf

We have a Ubuntu Docker container that runs a SSH server that we are trying to port over to Red Hat 8.4. I am trying to install the `openssh-server` package using the `dnf` package manager via my Dockerfile. The package fails to install with the error `Unable to find a match: openssh-server`. Am I trying to install the wrong package? All of the documentation I have been able to find says that is the name of the package.

EDIT: My system is configured with the following 3 repos:
`ubi-8-appstream`
`ubi-8-baseos`
`ubi-8-codeready-builder`

EDIT: Add image of dnf output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Red Hat Universal Base Image repos for their Docker images simply [do not include openssh-server](https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/x86_64/baseos/os/Packages/o/). I wasn't able to find a statement from Red Hat as to why, but given how extreme an antipattern it is to run an ssh server in a Docker container, it does make some sense.

If you have a paid Red Hat subscription, you could open a case with Red Hat and ask about having it added. But it's probably better to get rid of the ssh server entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Given the unique nature of the situation that is driving us to use SSH on a container...that is very disheartening.

Comment: you can use another custom repos and then you can install it.